# React-select.Async doesn't load options on onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I need a Async react-select, which will loadOptions from backend and users will be able to select multiple options. However when inputValue is already entered and users clicks on select input options is not being loaded. They are loaded only when you type something in.

[Example code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/n4j0wrl9kp)

[Input value stays the same](https://codesandbox.io/s/n4j0wrl9kp)

**EDIT: answer**

To reload default options you need to pass defaultOptions to Async select, not just true. This can be done by setting defaultOptions to state in componentDidMount and listening for 'menu-close' action in onInputChange and setting defaultOptions to state there. This will ensure that when the component is mounted the defaultOptions will be there, and when menu is closed, the options will be refetched with new inputValue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reload default options you need to pass defaultOptions to Async select, not just true. This can be done by setting defaultOptions to state in componentDidMount and listening for 'menu-close' action in onInputChange and setting defaultOptions to state there. This will ensure that when the component is mounted the defaultOptions will be there, and when menu is closed, the options will be refetched with new inputValue.

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/5yrr5vj8rx)

Answer (score 8):

To have react-select autoload content you must provide the `defaultOptions` prop. If you don't autoload then it won't make your async call until they attempt to filter.

```
<AsyncSelect loadOptions={myAsyncMethod} defaultOptions />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works on first load, however if i change inputValue, then clear the input, options list stays the same. I've added additional sandbox.

Comment: That gives me some more info. Though you can set `inputValue` through props, it's not immediately recognized in react-select lifecycle, and `inputValue` state is already controlled inside the component. Also the `loadOptions` method takes the `inputValue` as an argument, and this is what you would use in your filter. What's your reason behind trying to control the inputValue externally? I forked your example to show some working usage on the filtering you were trying to show. https://codesandbox.io/s/rr00y31k7q

Comment: Our select will query users from BE. And selected users will be selected into list. So f.e. user enters department name, and wants to select multiple users from it, i'd like the input value to not disappear when user selects user, or input loses focus, so the user wouldn't have to enter department on each occasion.